# LaTeX font missing on Windows machine

Tags: fonts, installing

[image: LaTeX Error]

What is going on here? I'm familiar with TeX, but I don't know much about fonts.

Comment: Do not post only screen shot but also some code that might help

Comment: This font is used in the customized latex class file. I don't have these fonts in my local %fonts% directory. Help to use further

Comment: you have to run the document with `xelatex` or `lualatex` if you want to use a system font.

Comment: This just means that the font your class file wants to use isn't properly installed. This actually can't be solved in the realm of TeX as you have to just get the font and install it properly. If you won't provide further detail that explains your problems conncection to TeX it is likely that your question will be closed (for the simple reason that this Q&A format is exclusively dedicated to questions concerning (La)TeX (and friends)).